# How can I reference a ListObject with a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Excel that is generated by querying an SQL database, so I end up with a table that has column titles of, say, A, B, C, D, E.

I want to populate an array in VBA based on the user's selection. For example, if Cell A1 has A in it, the array will be populated with the data from Column A. If the Cell A1 has B in it, the array will be populated with the data from Column B and so on.

I am currently trying to use the following code:

```
Sub Compare()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim Xaxis As Variant
    Set WS = Worksheets("SQL Table") 'sheet that has SQL generated table
    Set lo = WS.ListObjects("Table") 'Table is the name of the table

    Dim A As String

    A = WS.Range("A1").Value 'A1 in this case has the value A in it
    Xaxis = Worksheets("SQL Table").ListObjects("Table").ListColumns(A).DataBodyRange

End Sub
```

but get an error on the line that attempts to use the string variable A as a reference in a Listcolumn.

If I throw `""` around A it works, but then it's not a variable. I can accomplish what I want by using Case for each of the give options, but I would like to make it more streamlined. Is there a way I can use a variable to reference a Listobject, for that matter a Worksheet and so on?

Comment: There isn't actually anything wrong with your code, though you should use `lo` on the last line. Are you sure the value in A1 on SQL Table is the name of a column? What's the actual error?

Comment: Hello Rory, Thank you for that comment. I went back and realized that I never said it in my question but the A1 value was actually on another sheet. However, in the code I was still on the SQL table sheet that had no value in A1. I added 'Set WS = Worksheets ("Sheet6")' where the A1 value actually was after 'Dim A' and everything works now. Thanks again for your help reviewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Changes include:

- Dim'd Xaxis as Range
- Use Set keyword
- Took advantage of the objects already constructed

The code

```
Sub Compare()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim Xaxis As Range
Set WS = Worksheets("SQL Table") 'sheet that has SQL generated table
Set lo = WS.ListObjects("Table") 'Table is the name of the table

Dim A As String

A = WS.Range("A1").Value 'A1 in this case has the value A in it
Set Xaxis = lo.ListColumns(A).DataBodyRange

End Sub
```